# Nodemon not restarting the app from the package.json's script

Tags: node.js, nodemon

The part of my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js"}
```

If I run:

```
npm run start
```

the app run but if i change and save a file nodemon is not restarting the app

Note: no output message about nodemon at all

But if I run:

```
nodemon server.js
```

then it works.

Output:

> [nodemon] 1.19.1
>   [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
>   [nodemon] watching: *.*
>   [nodemon] starting `node server.js`

Any clue?

Comment: Did you see any output differences when running those 2 commands? `nodemon` output should have some starting lines with `[nodemon]` as prefix.

Comment: @NguyễnViệtĐức I edited the answer. I only see the output of nodemon on the second case

Comment: How did you install nodemon? Can you try reinstall and install again as a global dependency.

Comment: Installed globally, now I uninstalled, installed again and still the same